# Buildr won't generate a POM in projects with multiple packages

Tags: java, buildr

I have a Java project that uses Apache Buildr as its build tool.  It installs a WAR and two ZIP archives to a Maven repository.  However, with Buildr 1.5.6, it seems that when the instructions to build the ZIP archives are added to the buildfile there is no .pom file generated in the output folder.

To be specific, when executing `buildr clean package` using this buildfile code:

```
task :package => [:get_svn_version] 
SQL_ARCHIVE = "Project-#{VERSION_NUMBER}-sql.zip"
package(:zip, :file => _(:target, SQL_ARCHIVE)).include("src/main/sql")
CONF_ARCHIVE = "Project-#{VERSION_NUMBER}-conf.zip"
package(:zip, :file => _(:target, CONF_ARCHIVE)).include(_("conf"))
package(:war).with :libs => [PACKAGE_ONLY_DEPS, COMPILE_PACKAGE_DEPS]
```

...Buildr produces an output folder containing:

`atg@host:> ls target
classes  Project-1.1-SNAPSHOT-conf.zip  Project-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war  test
js-test  Project-1.1-SNAPSHOT-sql.zip   resources`

Whereas, just this:

```
task :package => [:get_svn_version]
package(:war).with :libs => [PACKAGE_ONLY_DEPS, COMPILE_PACKAGE_DEPS]
```

...outputs:

`atg@host:> ls target
classes  js-test  Project-1.1-SNAPSHOT.pom  Project-1.1-SNAPSHOT.war  resources  test`

As you can see, the .pom file is not generated in the former case, so `buildr install` cannot subsequently succeed.  My question, therefore, is **how can I get Buildr to create a .pom file as well as my WAR and ZIP archives?**

### EDIT:

The following simple buildfile is enough to reproduce the issue:

```
# Generated by Buildr 1.5.6, change to your liking
repositories.remote << 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2'

DUMMY_DEPENDENCIES = 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3'

desc "Test project for stackoverflow.com"
define 'no-pom' do
  project.group = "test"
  project.version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

  test.with DUMMY_DEPENDENCIES

  package(:zip, :file => _("target", "configuration.zip")).include(_("conf"))
  package(:war).with :libs => [DUMMY_DEPENDENCIES]

end
```

This is based on the classic Maven2 auto-generated project, with `App.java` and the "rigorous" `AppTest.java`.  All I added to it was the `conf` folder in the project root, which just contains one dummy text file.

If you run the above then you get a WAR and "configuration.zip" created but no .pom file.  If you comment out the instruction to zip the conf folder then you get a .pom file generated along with the WAR file.

Comment: Do you reproduce with earlier versions of Buildr such as 1.5.2?

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible use case?

Comment: Hi Antoine.  I'll attempt with 1.5.2 and get back to you.  I know that on my older dev machine it worked fine, and this version didn't have the `custom_pom.rb` code. Also, for what it's worth, this warning appears when executing the .pom file task: 
builder-3.2.2/lib/builder/xchar.rb:111: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

Comment: Turns out that it's exactly the same result with Buildr 1.5.2.  The `Project-1.1-SNAPSHOT.pom` file task is executed in the same way with the same deprecation warning but no actual .pom file is generated.  I'll try to make a small project to reproduce the bug in due course.

Comment: @AntoineToulme - I have added the test case to reproduce the issue as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any response to this question or acknowledgement of this as a Buildr bug, I've managed to work around the problem by modifying the offending file in Buildr.

In the file `/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/buildr-1.5.6/lib/buildr/java/custom_pom.rb` (path may vary depending on Ruby/Buildr version) look for this line:

`candidates = project.packages.select{|p| p.classifier.nil? }.collect{|p|p.type.to_s}`

It's line 181 for me, so it'll probably be there or thereabouts for most people.  Change it to read as follows:

`candidates = project.packages.select{|p|`**`defined? p.classifier &&`**`p.classifier.nil? }.collect{|p|p.type.to_s}`

Upon saving the file, you should be able to run `buildr clean package` and `buildr install` without any difficulty.

**Disclaimer:**  I am neither a Ruby programmer nor a Buildr developer, so this may be a breaking change for other areas of the software.  All I can say is that it works for me and has fixed this issue on my machine.